# pcap parsing with dpkt, python

Tags: python, regex, pcap, dpkt

i am relativly new to python and have a little project where i need to parse pcap and extract certain data. I am now stuck! What i need help with is how to parse de actual data content of the packet stream.

What i want to do is to be able to, for instance use a regular expression and if regexp match content of packet print.

Something like this

```
!/usr/bin/env python


import socket
import dpkt
import time
import re

f = open('pcap.pcap','r')
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)

pktCounter = 0


for ts,buff in pcap:

pktCounter += 1

try:
    ether = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buff)

    # Mac address
    src_mac = (ether.dst).encode("hex")
    dst_mac = (ether.src).encode("hex")
    smac = ':'.join([src_mac[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(src_mac), 2)])
    dmac = ':'.join([dst_mac[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(dst_mac), 2)])

    # Packet
    ip = ether.data
    tcp = ip.data
    src = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.src)
    srcport = tcp.sport
    dst = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.dst)
    dstport = tcp.dport

    # Definition of Time
    showTime = time.gmtime(ts)
    timeF = time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", showTime)

    # Packet Size
    sizeP = len(buff)


    # Data filtering
    p = re.compile("<Line>(.*?)\</Line>", re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)



    # Packet print
    print "PktNr: %s" %(pktCounter)
    print "PktSize: %s" %(sizeP)
    print "Time: %s" %(timeF)
    print "src: (MAC: %s) \033[1;32m(IP:%s)\033[1;m (port:%s) --> dest: (MAC: %s) \033[1;31m(IP:%s)\033[1;m (port:%s)" % (smac,src,srcport,dmac,dst,dstport) + "\n"
    print ip



except AttributeError:
    pass
```